# Cancel email in hook_mail

Tags: 8, emails

In hook_mail() I might discover that some part of the email couldn't be generated (maybe when trying to load a variable from an external system it fails).

How can I cancel the sending? I don't want to send an email with an error message in it.

Example code:

```
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'some_email':
      $foo = Something::fetchSomething($params['bar']);
      if (!$foo) {
        // I don't want to send this email any more
      }
      else {
        $message['body'][] = t('Important information about @foo.' ['@foo' => $foo]);
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Does that make sense? Or should all parameters be loaded and processed before hook_mail() and in hook_mail() you assume to always have those params available?

Comment: Just remove the `to` address maybe? Or don't set a body? It was something like that in D7, probably similar in D8. If all else fails, you can set `$message['send'] = FALSE;` in `hook_mail_alter()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the access check from [`hook_mail_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) instead of `hook_mail` (let it prepare the default message based on parameters, and alter it later) by something like:

```
function HOOK_mail_alter(&$message) {
  // can add additional check for particular mails here,
  // by checking the value in $message['id']
  if (TRUE) {
    $message['send'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

**Note:** You should clear the cache in order to make the changes effective.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `$message['send']`. It seems that `$message['send'] = FALSE` also works in `hook_mail()`. Is there any reason not to?

Comment: Only thing would be that it's undocumented so it could theoretically stop working any time. The likelihood is probably quite small though